# Groupbox in winform is not getting Refreshed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a groupbox which is containing controls like Textboxes,Lables,Comboboxes etc.Now i want to refresh this groupbox on button click.Here is the Codes that i am executing on button click but the refreshing is not happening in the groupbox.

```
    try
    {
        //MySqlConnection Mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlConnection Mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "DELETE FROM setting WHERE ToMailId='"+emailId+"'";
        Mysqlcon.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, Mysqlcon);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Mysqlcon.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted Successfuly");

        groupBox1.Refresh();


    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Not! Deleted !");
    }
```

Please help me..

Comment: It looks like your groupbox is getting refreshed - `Refresh` is just a simple draw call. Are you trying to update values? btw can you enter emailId as `id" OR true`?

Comment: @Sayse I want to clear all the values present in the textboxes,Comboboxes etc..

Comment: Then you need to loop through the controls and clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh don't update the values.
To update the values set the updated values in the groupbox again.

Here's a sample to help you

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) {
    switch (ctrl.GetType) {
        case typeof(TextBox):
            ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            break;
        case typeof(ComboBox):
            ((ComboBox)ctrl).Items.Clear();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("This type of control is not handled!!! Need to add a case for type " + ctrl.GetType.ToString);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for ur common code solution. But, dont u think that assigning combobox selected index to -1 is better than clearing whole item list. combobox can be bound and OP just selecting item from the list.

Comment: Yes, that is better but it depends upon the requirement of the OP. In the questions comment OP posted that he want to clear all values.

Comment: Than it means clear the selection if there is combo not the clear items. I hope u can understand what i am trying to say.